# Perl Template Toolkit - Preprocess templates back into Perl script

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

Forgive me if this question has already been asked and/or answered elsewhere.

Before I begin, I should point out that the nature of this inquiry may not require code to be added to this thread, rather the answer could simply be a link to the Template Toolkit module documentation with the comment "READ IT AGAIN" :).   To be even more clear, I would settle for a terse YES or NO answer.

Let's say I have a working perl script which processes Template::Toolkit templates without issue.

But, one of my templates contains "names" (person names, server names, in the end it really doesn't matter: just "names").  These names are used to create FILENAMES containing processed data later on.

Today, I have this working via the following pseudo-code:

```
$template->process('names.tt','output.txt');
```

I then take the generated list of "names" within "output.txt" and I push them into an array within the same executing Perl script.  This list is then used in an iterative fashion to output data specified in another template, and name each resultant file based on the original "name":

```
foreach(@names){
   my $filename = $_ . '.txt';
   $template->process('profile_doc.tt',$filename)
}
```

As I said, this all works fine (perfect, in fact).  My issue is that it bloats my code needlessly (got to manage open FHs, etc).  There has GOT to be a better way, given TT's extraordinary powers.

So I began reading about the included-modules of Template::Toolkit (e.g: STASH, PROVIDER, etc).  I understand STASH, for example, allows you to inject data into an existing template module object in a supplemental fashion, however this is the *polar opposite* of what I want to do.

My actual question (again, **YES** or **NO** would be just fine as answers in terms of whether or not this is possible):

Is it possible for a Perl script to read a template, say one that contains a *Template-Toolkit-stored HASH object*, and create a new HASH  that is *usable* by the actual Perl script (e.g: outside the template)?

If this were possible, it would negate the need to extract data in a convoluted fashion from one template and use that data to process the other template. Rather I could theoretically do the following without needing to manually populate a list which needs to be written to disk and then read again via FH.

```
foreach(sort keys $derivedhash{obj}){
   $filename = $_->{name} . '.txt';
   $template->process('profile_doc.tt',$_->{name});
}
```

Thank you, please understand I have done my best to create a usable pseudo-model as the real code involves confidential elements and, sadly, precludes disclosure.  I hope you'll understand.  I can provide other "scrubbed abstractions/examples" as needed.

**UPDATE**

In response to User ikegami:

First, thanks for responding.

OK, lets start with one of your comments:   " ... which makes no sense since TT doesn't store hashes" ...  Hmm.... Unless we're talking two separate things, this is incorrect as I am doing it today..  for example, here is a Template-hosted object that contains elements of the initial hash of which I spoke:

```
[%- SERVERS = [
      {entry={
              NAME => 'Server1'
              SERIAL => '1234567890'
              DESC => 'A file server'
      }}
      {entry={
              NAME => 'Server2'
              SERIAL => '0987654321'
              DESC => 'An account server'
      }}
]-%]
```

Once again, the above IS working, and it DOES exist in TT ...........  and unless I am mistaken, the above certainly looks, feels and tastes like a hash .... I grant you, however, that it is enclosed in an array ... so perhaps it is not a 100% Grade-A "Pure HASH object", but I certainly DO leverage it like a hash (and quite nicely, too).

Before you say anything, I already recognize I'll most likely need to update the **key** names to be UNIQUE for ease-of-parsing (hash keys by themselves should be unique), but that's a separate endeavor.

You were correct when you said "This is obviously not what you meant to ask".  Let me make the ultimate question clearer, as you requested:

*Can **Template Toolkit**, from within the executing Perl script read "Template 1" which contains a single HASH object (as described above), and read said HASH structure into a **new** hash object that exists only within the said executing-script (as opposed to the template itself)?  This "new hash" would be eventually used to name files generated by "Template 2".*

Lastly, to meet your last request:

The input excerpt above provides the "input" you requested.  The output I want would be a true Perl hash derived from the data inside the called Template.

So as a Perl equivalent (desired OUTPUT):

```
%newhash = (
    entry => {
        NAME => "Server1",
        SERIAL => "1234567890",
        DESC => "A file server"
    },
    .... other entries ....
);
```

.... would be used to "feed" specific values, say the "NAME" values, to other templates processed "later".

I hope this clears up the confusion ... thanks again ikegami ...

Comment: You can supply a subroutine reference as the 3rd argument to `process()` and the generated output will be passed as a parameter; you could then write the output and parse it at the same time, without having to read the file again. That still seems pretty roundabout, though.

Comment: Why are you using TT to generate a list of names? That seems like something better done in Perl; TT is very flexible, but beware of trying to do too much with a templating engine.

Comment: It sounds very much like whatever you have written for Template Toolkit in `names.tt` should be written in Perl. Perl can do everything that TT can do and a lot more besides. It's looks like the template takes no parameters, and so just creates names by combining literal strings; is that right?

Comment: Your additional notes only convince me further that this should be written in Perl instead of TT markup. How did the data get to be in a TT template file in the first place? Is there anything else in the template file apart from the hash that you show? Does it have to be in a template file for the purposes of any other process?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - thanks for your response(s).   I'll answer yours in the order presented.   1.) Thank you ... however I must ask, which is more roundabout ... my original (current fix) or your idea?  Somehow I think mine is worse :D  2.) Because said names themselves are stored in a TT-hosted object (see my later response to ikegami) ...  I do however take your comment seriously ("beware of trying to do too much with a templating engine") ... its possible, one day, we could store the said objects in something else (DB?) ... there are pros/cons to that, but it has come up before.  Thanks!

Comment: @Borodin, thanks for responding -- this was just how it initially started.  On one hand, yes we might have stored this data in a DB (or similar), but we wanted to keep as few distinct components involved, at least for this Proof-of-Concept.  That doesn't mean I am not **open** to such an idea in the near future. ;-).  To answer your second question, nothing else exists in these "data templates" containing the hash.  No subs, etc, just a plaintext hash/array obj :).  Lastly, your third question, "does it have to be in a template file?" No, and am open to other input "mediums". Thanks o/

Comment: @verteron: So perhaps there are other TT template files that use `INCLUDE` to get the information from `names.tt` and other files? It sounds to me as though you should be using a [*JSON*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file to store information like this. It stands for *JavaScript Object Notation*, and while it originated as the format for data literals in the JavaScript language, it has become a useful format for transferring data between languages. There are Perl, Python and Ruby libraries for reading it and you should look a the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) Perl module

Comment: @verteron: That means that any TT templates that need the data must have it passed to them in the call to `process` instead of being able to `INCLUDE` it directly, but I'm still unclear whether you ever do that anyway

Comment: Thank you @Borodin.  Ironically, JSON is one of the formats we optionally **output** downstream :).   I had not, however, considered using JSON as an **input** medium.  Thanks for this nifty idea.

Comment: It's not a good idea to store your raw data in a template. One of the biggest benefits of templates is that they allow you to separate display logic from business logic. By embedding all of your data in a template, you're forcing yourself to write complicated business logic to parse the results of your display logic, just to get at your raw data! You're also tying yourself to a single tool (TT) and a single language (Perl); you should use a common data serialization format like XML, YAML, or JSON (personally, I prefer JSON).

Comment: @verteron: Regarding your comment beneath your "answer" below, I wasn't suggesting that you should post it as a comment. There is an ***edit*** link beneath your question that also linked to in my comment. Any significant additional information that isn't just an answer to a comment should be added by editing your question. Anything posted as an *Answer* on Stack Exchange must be a solution to the original problem.

Comment: @Borodin, thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: "It's not a good idea to store your raw data in a template"  @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - thanks.  I am starting to see that is a common opinion held by many involved.  Though to be fair this is still what I would call Proof-of-Concept, and I must say its value was far greater than was initially thought (won't bore you with the details).  That said, its totally worth re-working and I am starting to see the value in doing so.  I consider this thread to have been most helpful and I believe I have what I need.  Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having a solution to accept, I thought I'd show some code that uses the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module to load some data from a disk file

Suppose my file `data.json` contains this (taken from your own sample data)

#### servers.json

```
[
  {
    "NAME"   : "Server1",
    "SERIAL" : "1234567890",
    "DESC"   : "A file server"
  },
  {
    "NAME"   : "Server2",
    "SERIAL" : "0987654321",
    "DESC"   : "An account server"
  }
]
```

Then I can write this Perl code to open and read the data into a Perl array of hashes, like this

#### servers.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.10.1;
use autodie;

use JSON;

use constant JSON_FILE => 'servers.json';

my $servers = do {
    open my $fh, '<:raw', JSON_FILE;
    local $/;
    decode_json <$fh>;
};

use Data::Dump;

dd $servers;
```

#### output

```perl
[
  { DESC => "A file server", NAME => "Server1", SERIAL => 1234567890 },
  { DESC => "An account server", NAME => "Server2", SERIAL => "0987654321" },
]
```

Note that I've used the [`autodie`](https://metacpan.org/pod/autodie) pragma to avoid having to manually check the status of the `open` call. `autodie` was first made a core module in Perl version 5.10.1 so I've required that as well

The `decode_json` call accepts only a *string* in JSON format, so I've used a `do` block to open and read the file and decode the contents, discarding all the temporary values like the file handle and the JSON string

[`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) is there only to show the form of the data structure read in

JavaScript data (JSON) is very like the equivalent Perl, except for the following

- Perl's `=>` is replaced with `:`
- Only double-quotes are allowed, no single quotes
- Hash keys, as well as string values, must be enclosed in quotes
- The last item of a list may not have a trailing comma

But there is no need to put quotes around a numeric literal value. It works the same as Perl, so that if you wish to retain a numeric string that has a leading zero then you will need to use quotes, otherwise the bare number is fine

I trust the reverse process—writing a JSON file—is obvious. A reference to a Perl data structure should be passed to `encode_json` to create a JSON string, which is then written to a file in the normal way

If you are desperate for some more speed in the encoding and decoding then there is a [`JSON::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) module which is partially written in C and so is much faster, however either JSON module will be very much faster than anything you chould set up with Template Toolkit. The XS variant is a drop-in replacement for the pure Perl version with regard to `encode_json` and `decode_json`

Answer (score 0):

TT produces text. But if TT were to produce a text representation of a hash, it could be easy to produce a hash from it.

Template:

```
[%- USE Template.Plugin.JSON -%]
[%- SERVERS = [ ... ] -%]
[%- SERVERS.json -%]
```

Code:

```
use JSON qw( from_json );

$template->process('template.tt', {}, \my $json)
   or die(...);

my $servers = from_json($json);
```

I used JSON, but any other means of serializing and deserializing the data structure would do as well.

---

That said, I'm completely clueless as to why you'd want to do this. You can't even take advantage of TT features that way!

If the point was to take advantage of TT features to vary the data structure, then making the template itself JSON would make far more sense. For example,

```
[
   [% IF devel %]
      {
         "entry": {
            "NAME":   "Server1-devel",
            "SERIAL": "1234567890",
            "DESC":   "Development server"
         }
      },
   [% ELSE %]
      {
         "entry": {
            "NAME":   "Server1-prod",
            "SERIAL": "1234567891",
            "DESC":   "Production server"
         }
      },
   [% END %]
   ...
]
```

```
use JSON qw( from_json );

my %vars = (
   devel => ...,
);

$template->process('template.tt', \%vars, \my $json)
   or die(...);

my $servers = from_json($json);
```

---

By the way, if you have a hash with a single constant key, you're doing something wrong.

```
[
   { entry => { NAME => "Server1", SERIAL => 1234567890, DESC => "A file server" } },
   { entry => { NAME => "Server2", SERIAL => "0987654321", DESC => "An account server" } },
]
```

should be

```
[
   { NAME => "Server1", SERIAL => 1234567890, DESC => "A file server" },
   { NAME => "Server2", SERIAL => "0987654321", DESC => "An account server" },
]
```

or

```
{
   "Server1" => { SERIAL => 1234567890, DESC => "A file server" },
   "Server2" => { SERIAL => "0987654321", DESC => "An account server" },
}
```

Comment: Hi again. I can clear up a couple things. 1st remember this is merely stage1: gather a list of names by which to create files.  when stage2 begins, we absolutely leverage the power of TT I promise you :).  The templates are very sophisticated, serve many purposes, and work wonderfully.  2nd, I know it seems strange but there is a good (long) answer as to why my obj is structured that way.  BUT, I will point out that due to this, and other unrelated issues, it seems we may be going with another backend altogether, e.g:     SQLITE <--in-- script.pl --out--> OUTPUT ... thanks!